# How does abi.encodePacked(...) and sha256(..) work in Solidity?

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, sha256, solidity, abi

I'm trying to implement a signature in a Solidity contract and I'm having problems when it comes to comparing hashes. I calculate the hash with the following code in solidity:

```
sha256(abi.encodePacked(param1, ...., paramN);
```

Where:

`abi.encodePacked(param1, ..., paramN) = [bytes: 0x0102030405060701]`

and

`sha255(abi.encodePacked(param1, ..., paramN)) = [bytes32: 
 0x245138c905599c8579ab186fbdbd6e62396aac35a98a6568f8803eed049d1251]`

The main problem I'm having is that by using python sha256 on *0102030405060701* the result I'm getting is *5bc31e3decf480124c79c114744d111ec82b62e466a097c3ced6fe76cbace9a5*.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you add your Python code? My guess is you're not using the correct hashing function. Solidity uses keccak256.

Comment: I calculate the hash using the same function as the one used in this web. By trying keccak256 it doesn't work eigther. (web: https://emn178.github.io/online-tools/sha256.html)

Comment: You need to do solidity‘s packed abi encoding before hashing. For JS there are things like ethereumjs-abi. I don’t know what the respective python libraries are. https://github.com/ethereumjs/ethereumjs-abi

Comment: Maybe this helps: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/29139/how-does-solidity-tightly-packed-arguments-work-in-sha256/46161

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that you're hashing the string "0102030405060701", but you should be hashing the bytes that hexadecimal value represents:

```py
>>> import hashlib
>>> import binascii
>>> hashlib.sha256(b'0102030405060701').hexdigest()
'5bc31e3decf480124c79c114744d111ec82b62e466a097c3ced6fe76cbace9a5'
>>> hashlib.sha256(binascii.unhexlify('0102030405060701')).hexdigest()
'245138c905599c8579ab186fbdbd6e62396aac35a98a6568f8803eed049d1251'
```

Note that hashing the string yields the same (incorrect) value you mentioned in your question, but first converting to binary via `unhexlify` yields the correct result, matching what you got in Solidity.